# C/C++ GUI apps using Visual Studio but with/without .NET

Tags: c++, c

I want to learn C/C++ GUI Windows/Linux programming. Which IDE is more suitable? If I go with Visual Studio.NET, what are the pros and cons of it.

Any IDE that supports both Windows and Linux?

Comment: It hasn't been called Visual Studio.NET in at least 3 versions. You can use it to create full unmanaged C++ applications without a single dependency on or reference to the .NET Framework. http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Qt Creator IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator) works for both Linux and Windows.

If you want a more versatile development environment, Qt can integrate with Eclipse.

Comment: I don't think Qt Creator integrates with Eclipse (they both do the same thing, i.e. they are both full-fledged IDEs). What exactly do you mean?

Comment: You're right - I meant to say that Qt integrates with Eclipse, with GUI design tools and all.

Answer (score 4):

I think Qt is best solution for you. It is intuitive, easy to learn GUI library. Also it is cross platform so you can write programs for Windows, Linux, Mac and phones.

For QT coding you can use QTCreator or Visual Studio Plugin for QT(only for Windows :)). For more information go to http://qt.nokia.com

Answer (score 2):

VS .Net is by far the bast development environment I've ever used. You can be incredibly productive with it.

Comment: Can I develop a non-.net variant with it?

Comment: Sure, you can develop standard C/C++.

Comment: But it won't be platform independent, however a great place to start.

Comment: Not true - of course you can write platform independent ANSI C/C++!